# Making text singular or plural based on variable length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make text singular or plural based on the value of `templateCount`. If `templateCount`'s value is 1 then I just want 'Template' to say that, but if `templateCount` is plural, I want it to say 'Templates Selected'.

What am I doing wrong with my code?

```
$('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Templates Selected" + templateCount.length == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

Comment: why don't you pull the ternary operation out and put it in its own variable and just add it?

Comment: Try keeping paranthesis `(templateCount.length == 1 ? "" : "s")`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted. Must be something outside.

Comment: `templateCount` is a number, I am wanting to change the word Template from "Templates Selected".

Comment: None of the posted answers considers the situation when `templateCount`  is `0`. Besides, the OP declared that `templateCount` is a number

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks. I was just going to ask about that as I am running into it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you thought this through? You have the string `"Templates selected"` there and you are conditionally appending `s` to the *end* of that (which would make it `"Templates Selecteds"`).

Do this:

```
$('#templateCount').html(templateCount + 
    " Template" + 
    (templateCount === 1 ? "" : "s") +
    " Selected");
```

Comment: `templateCount` is counting checkboxes checked... so since changing this code, whenever I deselect the length is off and this does not account for 0. I tried doing this, but it broke: `if (templateCount.length > 0) {
                            $('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");
                        }`

Comment: @Paul It sounds like `templateCount` is a number and that it doesn't have a `length`. I've now removed the `.length` portion from the above code. If it's actually an array (or something like an array), then `.length` should be used in _both_ places. It's not clear from your question exactly what `templateCount` is, but the use or non-use of `.length` should be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if what you mean is that you want to put an 's' on the end if templateCount == 1 or if templateCount's length is 1. Those can be two very different things.

If you want it based on the variable == 1, then I would try:

```
var templateCount;
// set it somewhere
var plural = templateCount === 1 ? "" : "s";
$('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template"+plural+ " Selected");
```

If it's the length you're actually after, change plural to

```
var plural = templateCount.length > 1 ? "" : "s";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function makeStatement(templateCount) {
  return templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") +" Selected";
}

console.log(makeStatement(1));
console.log(makeStatement(2));
```

And in your case

```
$('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");
```

Comment: `templateCount` is counting checkboxes checked... so since changing this code, whenever I deselect the length is off and this does not account for 0. I tried doing this, but it broke: `if (templateCount.length > 0) {
                            $('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");
                        }`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am reading your question wrong but wouldn't you just need to change the code to look like this?

`$('#templateCount').html(templateCount + " Template" + (templateCount.length == 1 ? "" : "s") + " Selected");`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var templateCount = [ 1 ];
function test() {
  var tmp = templateCount.length == 1 ? 1 : "Templates Selected";
  $("#test").val(tmp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">

<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```